# Method decidePolicyForNavigationAction never called, WKWebView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview

I am developing an app who shows a web page using WKWebView in Swift. I need to disable the user selection and the callout (because the web loads a graph) and I don't find any way to do this with WKWebView.

I am trying with this code but unfortunately it seems that this method is never called. Do you know in which part of my code may be the fault or what can I do?

```
public func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if (navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated){
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
}
```

This is my full code:

```
import WebKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "http://danfg95glucose.azurewebsites.net")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.load(request)

}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("loaded")

}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
        webView.load(navigationAction.request)
    }
    return nil
}


public func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if (navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated){
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }
}
}
```

Thank you so much for your responses. I am learning swift programming and I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 6):

forget _

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if (navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated){
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the "_" but it seems to be not called the function when the web finish load. Do you know what can I do?

Comment: This method is invoked whenever a server redirect is encountered, and before loading starts. from docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webpolicydelegate/1536273-webview?language=objc